# can i change parent class dynamically

Tags: java, struts2, struts

Below are my 2 Action classes, which extends different Action classes.

```
Employee1Action extends HRAction
Employee2Action extends ManagerAction
```

There is some common code in both Action Classes. I am thinking to copy that common code in another (CommonAction) Action class and Employee1Action and Employee2Action will extends to CommonAction. But both classes have different parent classes. Can i change CommonAction class's parent dynamically ? Means if pointer is in Employee1Action then CommonAction will extends to HRAction and same will be for Employee2Action class.can i do like this ? If yes how can i do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java you can't inherit from multiple parent classes- and of course delegation is a more flexible approach than inheritance.

You may extract an interface with the common operations from `Employee1Action` and `Employee2Action`; add an implementation and put the common code into this implementation. Then give to both `Employee1Action` and `Employee2Action` objects an instance of your implementation, and have them delegate the common operations to the delegate instance. In this way, you can remove the code duplication.

In code,

```
interface CommonAction {
  void doSomething();
}
class DefaulCommonAction implements CommonAction {
  public void doSomething() { 
    /* do something here -
     * this is the duplicate code from Employee 1 and 2 
     */
  }
}

class HRAction {}
class ManagerAction {}

class Employee1Action extends HRAction {
  private CommonAction action;
  public Employee1Action (CommonAction action){
    this.action = action;
  }
  // delegate operations
  public void doSomething() {
    action.doSomething();
  }
}
class Employee2Action extends ManagerAction {
  // the same delegation here
}
```

Comment: I agree with this answer.  You need to either have a deeper base that get's inherited from and from there split into individual inheritance trees or use interfaces if the logic doesn't need to be there (or can be default logic).